# How to use .sql files from command line with CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

I’ve got my application’s data model stored in a `.sql` file and want to run it against my Cockroach deployment. How do I execute the SQL file?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to execute a .sql file is to use `cockroach sql --database=[your database] < [import file].sql`.

This only needs to be run against one node of the cluster (or against your load balancer) because the schema and all of the data is automatically replicated and rebalanced throughout the cluster.

Comment: what if you want to create yours database from that SQL file?

Comment: @MayraNavarro Assuming you are already running Cockroach SQL shell, run `create database <database_name>`